# FabricJS: After deselect a group, the controllers appear rotated 180 degrees

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

After a deselect a group, if I selected a object, the controllers appears upside down (with a 180 degrees rotation).

Steps to reproduse the issue:

1. Select all objects
2. Deselect all objects
3. Select the triangle object (*in the example of the code above*)

```js
(function() {
    // Code from FabricJs tutorial - http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/#objects
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    
    // create a rectangle object
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 80,
      height: 40
    });
    
    var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
      left: 300,
      top: 100,
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      fill: 'blue',
      flipX: true
    });
    
    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.add(triangle);
    
    canvas.renderAll(); // this wasn't mentioned in the tutorial, but I'm pretty sure it's needed
})();
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>



<h1>Flip issue after grouping objects</h1>
<h2>None of the objects have rotation. Please select both objects (create a group) and, then, deselect it. After this, select the triangle : triangle will have rotation</h2>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

*I already open a [ticket](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4392) on the github with this issue.*

What I want to know, if there is any workaround that I could do to avoid this issue.

***Note:***

fabricJS 1.7.15 version.

Comment: I think it's a bug on 1.7.15 version, on 1.5 it's working well.

Comment: @artgb Yes, it is a bug, they already answered. But it seems they are fight back to not solve the issue :s